# Robotframework: How to execute token and secret in to defferent variables from String?

Tags: python, automation, robotframework

I have a response which I convert into the String

```
${string}=   convert to string   ${resp.content}
{"data":{"id":null,"type":"token","token":"<TokenID>","secret":"<SecretID>"}}
```

How can i save this  and  in to the different varibles? 
Thanks a lot.

Comment: is this content json? It looks a lot like json.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that this data is valid JSON, you can convert it to a dictionary and then use robot's extended variable syntax

Example:

```
${result}=  evaluate  json.loads($string)  json

should be equal  ${result["data"]["id"]}      ${NONE}
should be equal  ${result["data"]["type"]}    token
should be equal  ${result["data"]["secret"]}  <SecretID>
should be equal  ${result["data"]["token"]}   <TokenID>
```